# How to use 2 color scale for multiple conditions on same column in excel?

Tags: excel

Can someone tell me how to apply color scale on one column using multiple conditions?
For example I have below table. I want to highlight profit using green color scale(Higher the profift darker the shade of green) and losses using red(Higher the losses darker the color of red).
I tried applying color scale but it doesn't allow me to use 2 rules on same column using color scale.

[Sample Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NQ5Gh.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I think you don't need two conditions. Single color Scale can be applied. Greener for positive and red for negative. You have to apply it to all the cells of the profit column at  once in one rule.

Comment: When you use conditional formatting, the first option in colourscale "green-yellow-red" is exactly what you are looking for.

Comment: @NareshBhople :How can I apply shades using single color.. like highlight profit using green color scale(Higher the profift darker the shade of green)

Comment: @Dominique: I need only 2 colors that too with shades.lighter and darker for different values

Comment: If you want only green and red ... As mentioned by @Dominique you can select Green-Yellow-Red scale and then edit the format. Select white at the center instead of yellow. .... Or if you are looking for only green color for both profit and loss then select single color scale. That will give you dark green for max profit and whit for max loss.

Comment: @addy: I can only give you one advice: open the conditional formatting, and try the possibilities you have there. There are so much possibilities that I can't imagine none of them matching what you want.